# Задать новое xml содержимое для layout в Activity

Tags: android, android-layout

В моем `activity` есть несколько элементов, одни из которых кнопки и пока еще пустой `linearLayout`.

Мне нужно, что бы по нажатию на первую кнопку `linearLayout` показывал одну `xml` разметку, а по нажатию на вторую- другую разметку. В разметках содержатся разные `imageview` и кнопки, нажатие на которых тоже нужно обрабатывать.

**Как заполнять `linearLayout`?** **Правильно ли будет обрабатывать кнопки из разметок в `OnClickListner` в `activity` или там нужен какой-то другой подход?**

Comment: Пишете один xml, в котором нужные области обозначены `visibility="gone"`, кнопками потом их показываете или скрываете. Обычно все а одной активити, если разметка большая, есть смысл разбить ее на фрагменты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В целом вы все верно делаете, но я бы порекодмендовал сделать так:
В главном активити у вас есть кнопки, а вместо **LinearLayout** вы используете **FrameLayout**. Далее, по клику на кнопку, вы вставляете фрагмент, вместо **FrameLayout**. Таким образом, кликая по кнопкам, вы сможете менять текущий фрагмент на необходимый.

В этом вопросе неплохо затрагиваются все интересующий вас аспекты:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44414483/replace-child-fragment-dynamically-from-child-fragment-itself

Answer (score 1):

Eugene Krivenja вам все верно объяснил. Лучше всего делать работу с Фрагментами и использовать FrameLayout. Но если вы хотите добавить xml именно в linear, то можно это сделать таким образом:

```
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.ВАША XML, null);
LinearLayout linear =findViewById(R.id.Ваш Linear);
linear.addView(view);
```

Для последующего обновления, вы должны сначала удалить дочерний элемент linear, `linear.removeViewAt(linear.getChildCount());` ,а после опять добавить.